# Would it be possible for a share sheet item to open a specific browser?

Tags: ios, development

I'm thinking of a way to easily switch browser or simply open pages in Chrome by using the share sheet.

Can an app to create an icon in the share sheet that **opens a third-party app?** Does `UIActivityViewController` allow this?

[image: share sheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You will have to develop it yourself. Or the developers have to develop for their respective apps. I am a developer so this is an easy to do for me, but if your not a developer it may be more costly than its worth. Time, finances, hardware. You could look into jailbroken options though ( I don't know too much about that department )

If you are a developer look into the following :

`UIActivityViewController`

You will have to subclass it in order to customize it to your needs.

The proper documentation is located [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/index.html)

Comment: I was mainly concerned about API limitations: Could an icon link to an app you don't own (Safari or Chrome in this case)? I updated the post with clarifications

Comment: Yes. @bfred.it You would include the apps url scheme provided they have one, which they do you just have to figure it out. Use iTunes linker or something. Additionally a drawback of doing this is there is no guarantee a user has chrome installed so if you don't include if statements it will crash immediately

Comment: Thanks! There's a way to [detect other apps](https://github.com/danielamitay/iHasApp/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-does-it-detect-apps) like Chrome, since they have custom URL schemes. I suppose I only need to verify that Chrome allows me to open Safari by simply using the `http://` scheme.

Comment: @bfred.it see this post for more info. This is a dev reference, so valid [here](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/ios/links) additionally, opening apps from another app is now supported in iOS with extensions so don't worry about using private APIs Apple is all for it, and even prior to to iOS8 if you knew the url scheme it didn't matter. They won't reject your app

Comment: There's really no need for the github project @bfred.it I mean it's your app do whatever you want but you don't really need those files included in your project if you explicitly only care for Google chrome. The comment above has supported documentation on how to call Chrome iOS url scheme (and open links with it) but if you plan on doing it with a bunch of apps that you don't know, then sure that project looks viable based off my brief skim through of it